# Is it a proper way to get the response from Device Admin by onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-activity

I am trying to get the response from activate device admin by user.
if the user press activate then do somethings or if the user press cancel a dialog will pop to inform user should activate.

i try to use

In Class **DeviceAdmin**

```
public class DeviceAdmin {
    public static final int DEVICE_ADMIN_REQUEST = 9;
    public static final int START_SERVICE = 8;

    private static DevicePolicyManager mDevicePolicyManager;
    private static ComponentName mComponentName;

    public static DevicePolicyManager getDevicePolicyManager() {
        return mDevicePolicyManager;
    }

    public static void setDevicePolicyManager(
            final DevicePolicyManager devicePolicyManager) {
        mDevicePolicyManager = devicePolicyManager;
    }

public static ComponentName getComponentName() {
    return mComponentName;
}

public static void setComponentName(final ComponentName componentName) {
    mComponentName = componentName;
}


    public static void initDPM(final Activity activity) {
        if (mDevicePolicyManager == null) {
            setDevicePolicyManager((DevicePolicyManager) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE));
        }
    }

    public static <T> void initComponent(final Activity activity,
            final Class<T> reciever) {
        if (mComponentName == null) {
            setComponentName(new ComponentName(activity, reciever));
        }
    }

    public static boolean isDeviceAdmin() {
        return mDevicePolicyManager.isAdminActive(mComponentName);
    }

    public static void registerDeviceAdmin(final Activity activity,
            final int requestCode) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
        intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN,
                getComponentName());
        activity.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
    }

    public static void unregisterDeviceAdmin() {
        if (mDevicePolicyManager.isAdminActive(mComponentName))
            mDevicePolicyManager.removeActiveAdmin(mComponentName);
    }


}
```

In **MainActivity**

```
public class LockIt extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        init();
        if (!DeviceAdmin.isDeviceAdmin())
            DeviceAdmin.registerDeviceAdmin(this,
                    DeviceAdmin.DEVICE_ADMIN_REQUEST);
        else
            // Do something;
    }

    private void init() {
        DeviceAdmin.initDPM(this);
        DeviceAdmin.initComponent(this, LockItNowAdminReceiver.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == DeviceAdmin.DEVICE_ADMIN_REQUEST) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // do something;
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // showAdminDialog;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**RESULT_OK** is -1, **RESULT_CANCELED** is 0

But when I ran in debug mode, I found that no matter user press Cancel or Activate,
resultCode is always 0.

**UPDATE**

OKAY, I think I have found the reason. I used `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` in **Manifest of MainActivity**

Do this is a proper way to get the response of device admin activation?
Or I have do something wrong?

Comment: Post any code related to device admin, we can't guess

Comment: More codes are added. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally

I think I have found the reason.

I used `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` in Manifest of MainActivity

Now I use `android:taskAffinity`.
It seems everything okay now.

Comment: I was having an issue too, but your tip to remove that attribute from the Manifest helped.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that's true, but you should put an instance of a class extending `DeviceAdminReceiver`:

```
ComponentName mDeviceAdminSample = new ComponentName(v.getContext(), DeviceAdmin.class);

Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, mDeviceAdminSample);
activity.startActivityForResult(intent, DEVICE_ADMIN_REQUEST);
```

And in `onAcitivityResult`:

```
if (requestCode == DEVICE_ADMIN_REQUEST}

  if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    // admin
  } else {
   // not admin
  }

}
```

A complete sample can be found [here](https://github.com/marakana/DevicePolicyDemo/blob/master/src/com/marakana/android/devicepolicydemo/DevicePolicyDemoActivity.java)

Just get sure of declaring your receiver in the `AndroidManifest.XML`.

Comment: I have a receiver instance and I need to use these codes in two classes, therefore, I put the code into one static class as a static functions. However, one of the class works fine and can get -1 for activate but one of it always get 0.